# Is there a simple way to filter files by date across all directories?

Tags: 16.04, file-sorting

I have a 64GB SD card mass storage. I recently bought a 64GB USB drive to duplicate all my files from the SD card in case of a failure.
I would like to keep a daily update of the USB drive to mirror the SD card.
How can I sort all the files across all directories on the SD card by date to select the most recent for copying?

Answer (score 4):

Basically if you want to have a full backup you should use something like `rsync` or a complete backup solution to create incremental backups.

However for your question, I guess `find` can be helpful:

```
find /media/username/sdcard -mtime -1
```

The above command would find all files modified from yesterday till now.

Comment: I agree: rsync is made for this.